# "as each other" as used to compare two things

Tags: comparatives

I've nevr come across such comparative pattern as in this sentence (it's taken out of an English text book): *But Lucy and Sam are as forgetful as each other*.

What's the meaning of the structure? Is it *Lucy and Sam are equally forgetful?*

Comment: Yes, sounds right.

Comment: It's not limited to two compared items / people / concepts. [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/equal) has: 'All people are equal, deserving the same rights as each other.'

Comment: I.e., it expands into "Lucy is as forgetful as Sam, and Sam is as forgetful as Lucy. Lucy and Sam are *each* as forgetful as *the other*."

Comment: Also: Welcome! If you're learning English, there's a Stack Exchange dedicated to [English language learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) that you might also find useful.

Comment: @AndyBonner Thank you! I'm new here, what's the difference between English language learners and where I'm posting my questions now? And also how did you make this English language learners clickable?(

Comment: Well, they both cover English, of course, but English Language Learners is specifically about helping folks with the kinds of questions people run up against when learning a secondary language. The piped link is done by putting what you want to appear in square brackets, followed immediately by parentheses containing the url, [ like this ] ( url.com ) , but without the spaces.

Comment: By the way, if you're new to Stack Exchange in general, there's a quick [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) that explains how things work.

Comment: @AndyBonner, thanks a lot for your help!